# Search exact text in a string

Tags: string, sql-like, exact-match

I am querying a SQL Server DB. I have a field "Remarks" that contains values pipe delimited as such
59P|W26|W511|862|W51

I'm trying to search in this field for an exact match, for example in the above I just want to return W51 not W511. I thought contains would help but unfortunately the table is not full text indexed and I dont have the ability to change that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can the string appear in any column?  In your example, it appears in the last column.

Comment: @thebiggestlebowski this is all one column/field. The string can be in any part of the field. I should have clarified, thanks for asking.

Comment: I think you need to run downstream logic to filter out the results you don't want.  That logic can be a stored procedure in the database itself or it can be on the application which queries the database.  I don't see how to do this with just SQL.  If the substring is found between delimiters, then you're good (|W51|).  However, that's not good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can do this using sql server because it has a useful built in function.  Check out https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_split-function/

Comment: You can search stack overflow or the internet on how to use it exactly as you need.  You should be able to create a temporary result set using spilt and then select the rows which have a match from the original table.

Comment: Thank you! This actually helped me for another issue I was having.

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Comment: Glad to help Tia ;)